# How to get Dynamic Variable assigned with dynamic values in loops

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have created a **loop** for getting dynamic variables like this:

```
var tile;
var tiles;
while(i<16){
this['tile'+i]=this['tiles'+i];
i++;
}
```

I expected it to return :

```
tile1=tiles1
tile2=tiles2
tile3=tiles3........
```

(tiles1,tiles2,tiles3.. means value of predefined varibles tiles1,2,3...)
It does return the variable name(left side of'=') but doesn't return the value (right side of'=').
I am new in JavaScript. Hope I could explain the problem.
How to solve this?

I tried

```
 this['tile'+i]=tiles+i;
 this['tile'+i]=tiles[i];
 this['tile'+i]="tiles"+i;
```

But doesn't help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is really going on here since the variables you are trying to read haven't been defined in the code you are sharing, and the value of `this` depends on where the code is running. You need to provide a [mcve]. What's more, you **should not** be using sequentially numbered variable names in the first place. We have [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the variables without the `var` keyword then they're going to be stored inside the global this, so you can do the following:

```js
tiles1 = 1;
tiles2 = 2;
tiles3 = 3;
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    globalThis['tile'+i] = globalThis['tiles'+i];
}
```

Now `console.log(tile2)` will print `2` as desired.

Comment: Bro tiles1,tiles2,.... Were defined earlier but still this doesn't help.